# Estimate a probit regression model with optim()

Tags: r, optimization, regression, logistic-regression, glm

I need to manually program a probit regression model without using `glm`. I would use `optim` for direct minimization of negative log-likelihood.

I wrote code below but it does not work, giving error:

> cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

```
# load data: data provided via the bottom link
Datospregunta2a <- read.dta("problema2_1.dta")
attach(Datospregunta2a)

# model matrix `X` and response `Y`
X <- cbind(1, associate_professor, full_professor, emeritus_professor, other_rank)
Y <- volunteer

# number of regression coefficients
K <- ncol(X)

# initial guess on coefficients
vi <- lm(volunteer ~ associate_professor, full_professor, emeritus_professor, other_rank)$coefficients

# negative log-likelihood
probit.nll <- function (beta) {
  exb <- exp(X%*%beta)
  prob<- rnorm(exb)
  logexb <- log(prob)
  y0 <- (1-y)
  logexb0 <- log(1-prob)
  yt <- t(y)
  y0t <- t(y0)
  -sum(yt%*%logexb + y0t%*%logexb0)
  }

# gradient
probit.gr <- function (beta) {
  grad <- numeric(K)
  exb <- exp(X%*%beta)
  prob <- rnorm(exb)
  for (k in 1:K) grad[k] <- sum(X[,k]*(y - prob))
  return(-grad)
  }

# direct minimization
fit <- optim(vi, probit.nll, gr = probit.gr, method = "BFGS", hessian =  TRUE)
```

data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B06Id6VJyeb5OTFjbHVHUE42THc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As soon as I saw `read.dta("problema2_1.dta")` I suspected that you needed desperately to read [MCVE]

Comment: thanks for the comments, im a noob using r, i used pnorm , changed y to Y and add the "+" and the program worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**case sensitive**

`Y` and `y` are different. So you should use `Y` not `y` in your defined functions `probit.nll` and `probit.gr`.

These two functions also do not look correct to me. The most evident problem is the existence of `rnorm`. The following are correct ones.

**negative log-likelihood function**

```
# requires model matrix `X` and binary response `Y`
probit.nll <- function (beta) {
  # linear predictor
  eta <- X %*% beta
  # probability
  p <- pnorm(eta)
  # negative log-likelihood
  -sum((1 - Y) * log(1 - p) + Y * log(p))
  }
```

**gradient function**

```
# requires model matrix `X` and binary response `Y`
probit.gr <- function (beta) {
  # linear predictor
  eta <- X %*% beta
  # probability
  p <- pnorm(eta)
  # chain rule
  u <- dnorm(eta) * (Y - p) / (p * (1 - p))
  # gradient
  -crossprod(X, u)
  }
```

**initial parameter values from `lm()`**

This does not sound like a reasonable idea. In no cases should we apply linear regression to binary data.

However, purely focusing on the use of `lm`, you need `+` not `,` to separate covariates in the right hand side of the formula.

---

## reproducible example

Let's generate a toy dataset

```
set.seed(0)
# model matrix
X <- cbind(1, matrix(runif(300, -2, 1), 100))
# coefficients
b <- runif(4) 
# response
Y <- rbinom(100, 1, pnorm(X %*% b))

# `glm` estimate
GLM <- glm(Y ~ X - 1, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

# our own estimation via `optim`
# I am using `b` as initial parameter values (being lazy)
fit <- optim(b, probit.nll, gr = probit.gr, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)

# comparison
unname(coef(GLM))
# 0.62183195  0.38971121  0.06321124  0.44199523

fit$par
# 0.62183540  0.38971287  0.06321318  0.44199659
```

They are very close to each other!

Comment: thank, Do you have an idea how to program a marginal effects without using mfx?